# How to use table values as Enum with Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table populated with Titles such as Mr, Miss, Mrs, Ms, Dr etc

How could i use these values as Enums if i am using the Code First approach? Especially if i want to keep them in sync between the table and Code First?

Background: I reverse engineered this by creating the database first and then using ADO .Net Entity Data model to produce the Code First template which i can use as a guide but not using the Edmx file.

I see a few articles with EDMX files but non in this manner?

Comment: Entity Framework 6 (unlike Entity Framework Core) supports Enums out of the box. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-types/enums) Microsoft docs link for more information

Comment: Better not to use them as enum, keep them in a table. Otherwise you will have a lot of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a T4 template (the following is done with Entity Framework 6 code first). After following the instructions below, if the data changes rerun the T4.

Full source in the following [GitHub repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/EntityFrameworkEnum).

- Add a new file named PersonTitle.ttinclude.
- Set `Custom tool` to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`
- Change `connectionString` to your database connection string
- In the example below, I have three columns, `Id` primary key, `Title` for Mr, Miss e.g.
- `columnDescription` for description (this of course is optional but if not present remove it from the select statement.

Once done, save the file, you should get a prompt asking to continue, accept it. At this point Visual Studio runs the code. If there are problems they will be shown in the Output window.

If no issues you get the output shown below in figure 2.

Create a new file, name is PersonTitles.cs, copy code in figure 2 and adjust as in figure 3.

For a demonstration, since I don't have tables/models ready the following is taken from my Microsoft TechNet article [Entity Framework database/Code First Enum support](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53169.entity-framework-databasecode-first-enum-support.aspx). [CategoriesName](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/EntityFrameworkEnum/blob/master/NorthWindLibrary/Classes/CategoriesNames.cs) is an enum.

```
public List<Product> GetProducts(CategoriesName categoriesName)
{
    using (var context = new NorthWindContext())
    {
        return context.Products
            .Where(prod => prod.CategoryID == categoriesName)
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductName)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

**Figure 1**

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="EnvDTE.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#
    var tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Host.TemplateFile);
    var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
    var columnId = "Id";
    var columnName = "Title";
    var columnDescription = "columnDescription";
    var connectionString = "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=NorthWindAzureForInserts;integrated security=SSPI";

    // Get containing project
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)Host;
    DTE dte = (DTE)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
    Project project = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile).ContainingProject;
#>
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace <#= project.Properties.Item("DefaultNamespace").Value #><#= Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile).Remove(0, Path.GetDirectoryName(project.FileName).Length).Replace("\\", ".") #>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <#= tableName #> auto generated enumeration by Karen Payne
    /// </summary>
    [GeneratedCode("TextTemplatingFileGenerator", "10")]
    public enum <#= tableName #>
    {
<#
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string command = string.Format("select {0}, {1}, {2} from {3} order by {0}", columnId, columnName, columnDescription, tableName);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(command, conn);

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    bool loop = reader.Read();

    while(loop)
    {
#>      
        /// <summary>
        /// <#= reader[columnName] #> 
        /// </summary>
        <#= Pascalize(reader[columnName]) #> = <#= reader[columnId] #><# loop = reader.Read(); #><#= loop ? ",\r\n" : string.Empty #>
<#
    }
#>  }
}
<#+
    private string Pascalize(object value)
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?<first>[a-zA-Z0-9])(?<reminder>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*)");
        return rx.Replace(value.ToString(), m => m.Groups["first"].ToString().ToUpper() + m.Groups["reminder"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
#>
```

**Figure 2**

```
[GeneratedCode("TextTemplatingFileGenerator", "10")]
public enum PersonTitle
{
  
    /// <summary>
    /// Mr 
    /// </summary>
    Mr = 1,

  
    /// <summary>
    /// Miss 
    /// </summary>
    Miss = 2,

  
    /// <summary>
    /// Mrs 
    /// </summary>
    Mrs = 3,

  
    /// <summary>
    /// Dr 
    /// </summary>
    Dr = 4
}
```

**Figure 3**

```
public enum PersonTitles : int
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Mr 
    /// </summary>
    Mr = 1,


    /// <summary>
    /// Miss 
    /// </summary>
    Miss = 2,


    /// <summary>
    /// Mrs 
    /// </summary>
    Mrs = 3,


    /// <summary>
    /// Dr 
    /// </summary>
    Dr = 4
}
```

[image]